# Renaming Files and Directories Recursively using rename/find

Tags: linux, centos, find, rename

I started learning linux on vmware using centos 7. I created an image directory and several layers of files and sub-directories in that folder. most of the names containing spaces. I want to use a single command to rename all the files and directories at once.

command i am using right now is

```
find . -type f -exec rename "find" "replace" {} \;
&
find . -type d -exec rename "find" "replace" {} \;
```

Where as find is a space and replace is "-"(hiphen). I even tried below command looking at one of the answer in stack exchange.

```
find . -iname "find" -exec rename "find" "replace" {} \;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're going to rename directories under `find`'s nose, tell it to act on the content of a directory before the directory itself, with `-depth`. On the other hand, doing directories separately from regular files doesn't help.

To rename a file with the tools that are available on a default CentOS installation, you can use a shell and `mv`. Take care to change only the base name, not the directory name (since the new directory doesn't exist yet).

```
find . -depth -exec bash -c '
  for filename do
    basename=${filename##*/}
    mv "$filename" "${filename%/*}/${basename// /-}"
  done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry i did not understand how for .. do is working here. -depth works for any number of depth? 
and is it working like this for `dir1/dir2/dir3...` 
1. Go through files in dir1 then dir1,
2. Go through files in dir2 then dir2. and so on...

Comment: @SyedMudabbir Yes, `-depth` means to go through `dir2` before `dir1`, and `dir3` before `dir2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Usual `zsh` answer to this kind of question:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -v '(**/)(* *)' '$1${2// /-}'
```

It takes care of processing the files depth-first, and checks for conflicts or overwrites (regular files only) better than you'd usually do by hand.